# Best order for KeyboardAvoidingView, SafeAreaView and ScrollView

Tags: react-native, scroll, keyboard, safeareaview

I use react native to create a mobile app. I handle keyboard position in my screens by using KeyboardAvoidingView, SafeAreaView and ScrollView.
I use this order to manage Keyboard position :

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView style={{ flex: 1 }} behavior="padding" enabled>
        <SafeAreaView>
          <ScrollView>
            <Header
              leftComponent={{
                icon: "cancel",
                color: "#fff",
                size: 30,
                onPress: () => navigate("Dashboard")
              }}
              centerComponent={{ text: "Ajouter une demande", style: { color: "#fff", fontSize: 18 } }}
              rightComponent={{
                icon: "help",
                color: "#fff",
                size: 30,
                fontWeight: "bold",
                onPress: () => Alert.alert("En cours de développement")
              }}
              backgroundColor="rgba(82, 159, 197, 1)"
              // outerContainerStyles={{ height: Platform.OS === "ios" ? 70 : 70 - 24 }}
              containerStyle={
                {
                  // marginTop: Platform.OS === "ios" ? 0 : 15
                }
              }
            />
            <View>
              <Input placeholder="INPUT WITH CUSTOM ICON" leftIcon={<Icon name="user" size={24} color="black" />} />
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

My question is : what's the best order to use those 3 components to avoid a best keyboard position

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SafeAreaView` only works with `iOS`. Therefore, it is assumed that you use the `iOS`. If your project is `iOS`, you can use `KeyboardAwareScrollView`.

`SafeAreaView` should be at the top because it covers the area of the screen.

**KeyboardAwareScrollView Example**

[image: gifimage]

**Usage**

```js
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view'
...
<SafeAreaView>
<KeyboardAwareScrollView>
  <View>
    <TextInput />
  </View>
</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: Hello, you recommend to use this librairie instead of the native KeyboardAvoidingView component ?

Comment: Yes,  @KhaledIf if you create the iOS project, you can work much more comfortably.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a re-usable component example without library and includes KeyboardAvoidingView, SafeAreaView and ScrollView. It also makes scrollview expand to full height.

```
import { KeyboardAvoidingView, SafeAreaView, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';

const ScreenContainer = props => {
  const { children } = props;
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={ { flex: 1 } }>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior={ Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height' }
        style={ { flex: 1 } }
      >
        <ScrollView
          contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
        >
          { children }
        </ScrollView>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default ScreenContainer;
```

Comment: I mapped an array of 20 TextInputs inside of children in your example and it didn't work. The scroll doesn't go below actual input I clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an another solution without the need of an external library such as `react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view`.

I made a `ScreenWrapper` component to handle the IOs issue:

```js
import React, { ReactElement } from 'react';
import {
  KeyboardAvoidingView, Platform,
} from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

const ScreenWrapper = ({ children }: Props): ReactElement => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      {
        Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? (
            <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{ flex: 1 }} behavior="padding">
              {children}
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
          )
          : (
            <>
              {children}
            </>
          )
      }
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default ScreenWrapper;
```

As Android looks to make the things greatly without the `KeyboardAvoidingView`, I decided to use it only for IOs, it's simpler to manage.

I use the `padding` because it fits my need but you may want to change it.

I recommend to read [this excellent blog post](https://blog.hackajob.co/using-the-keyboardavoidingview-in-react-native/) for more information. I created this wrapper thanks to it.

Comment: I mapped an array of 20 `TextInput`s inside of `children` in your example and it didn't work. The scroll doesn't go below actual input I clicked on.